# nginx - serving an SPA with different routes

Tags: nginx

I have a bundle in /usr/app/build.  It has an index.html.

I want:

1. Requests to /build to be served from /usr/app/build
2. Any other requests to be answered by /usr/app/build/index.html

That's it!

The below doesn't work (gives 404).  Nor does replacing the `try_files` argument with `/build/index.html`, nor does having an explicit location for `/index.html` and having the `try_files` argument of `/index.html`.

```
location /build {
    alias /usr/app/build;
}

location / {
    try_files /usr/app/build/index.html =404;
}
```

I'm baffled.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any location that serves files must have a `root` or `alias`, or inherit the value from a surrounding block. In your case `root` is more efficient that `alias` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details).

The file elements of the `try_files` statement is appended to the `root` value to generate the pathname of the returned file. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
root /usr/app;
location /build {}
location / {
    try_files /build/index.html =404;
}
```

---

The `=404` is largely redundant if `/usr/app/build/index.html` always exists. It would be more usual to place the default action at the end of the `try_files` statement, for example:

```
root /usr/app;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /build/index.html;
}
```

But the above does not meet the exact requirement of "any other requests".